# Where is the control panel in ubuntu for uninstall any installed software

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall

I am new for Ubuntu recently I have installed some software on my Ubuntu machine, I want to uninstall some software from my system but I don't no where the control panel of Ubuntu like windows have control panel it shows which software installed in your system and give the option to uninstall any software so it is possible in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know where `dash` is?

Comment: i don't know where dash is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them in `dash`. Type "software center" and the "image" below will be seen, click on the "Software Center tool". **Note your `dash` will be located at the *top left* of your screen, mine I had move to the bottom of my screen. To open `dash` click on the __Ubuntu logo**:

[image]

Now when it opens go to the installed tabs and you will see your installed apps and there you can uninstall:

[image]

Then if you wish to use the `terminal`, these are the steps:

1. Check installed apps with:

   apt-cache pkgnames
2. Remove with:

   sudo apt-get remove application_name

Answer (score 0):

You can search for **Software Center** 
Or try to install it yourself 
open terminal:

> ctrl+alt+t

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

then open the **software center** via terminal

```
sudo software-center
```

Another way you can uninstall what you want via terminal directly without software center
such as

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome
```

I hope that help you.